# How to get specific characters in url and store to id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url

For example i have this URL

http://localhost:3000/legone/survey/surveyform/form11/03141800300000030001

and i want to store in id A the first 11 characters in the last part "031418003000"
then the next 4 characters to id B "0003"
and 
the last four characters to id C "0001"

i tried pathname split but it depends on a character. Thanks!

Comment: is your string always going to be in last part of / separator ?

Comment: Yes, the numbers only at the end

Comment: "031418003000" is 12 characters

Comment: oh its only a typo error. Sorry!

Comment: anyways you have got the ans :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort sir, already got the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.prototype.substr` or `String.prototype.substring`, or a regular expression. Here's how you do the latter:

```
var regex = /(\d{11})(\d{4})(\d{4})$/;
var match = regex.exec(window.location.href);
var A = match[1], B = match[2], C = match[3];
```

Comment: Thanks! ill try this

Answer (score 1):

I like to use string split!

```
var url = window.location.href;
var urlArray = url.split("/");
var bigIdString = urlArray[urlArray.length-1];
var A = bigIdString.substring(0,11);
var B = bigIdString.substring(11,15);
```